# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql

While executing the below code getting this error; I do not understand why this exception occurs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:799)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1038)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:839)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3329)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:32)




    String query = "select usrid, status, mob, msg from ( "
                    + "selet usrid, status, mob, msg, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by usrid) R from smsreport "
                    + ") where R BETWEEN 2 AND 10 ";

            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

When the same query executes in a SQL database, it is executing well.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: `selet`? No subquery alias also....

Comment: thanks a lot , juergen d ! I struggled for a hour for this silly mistake, anyway thanks once again for your correction written selet instead of select.